# Parse JSON using Apex classes

Tags: apex, class, json

I would like to replace my current code with the JSON2APEX classes generated however I am unsure how to do this. 
My current class:

```
public with sharing class LeadAPIHandler {

    // the Reed API handler
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void reedLeadAPIHandler() {

        // if we get an exception in the callout, or when trying to insert the leads, log the error.            
        try {                

            HttpResponse res = issueReedCallOut();
            system.debug(res.getBody());
            parseReedCalloutResponse(res);      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log exeption to error log 
        }  
    }

    public static void parseReedCalloutResponse(HttpResponse res) {

        /* Expecting a response in this format
            "totalItemCount": 8,
            "totalPages": 1,
            "leads": [
            { 
              "enquiryId": 1210063, 
              "courseId": 29346,
              "providerCourseRef": null,
              "createdOn": "2015-01-23T13:01:37",
              "firstName": "Christopher",
              "lastName": "Wright",
              "email": "amoskia@hotmail.com",
              "phone": "970569778406",
              "country": null,
              "postcode": null,
              "comment": null,
              "courseTitle": "BTEC Level 3 Certificate in Mechanical Engineering"
            }
            */

            // get the JSON response to parse
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
            List<Lead> parsedLeads = new List<Lead>();
            Lead l = null;    

            ID leadsQueue = [ SELECT queue.id FROM queuesobject WHERE queue.name='Inbound Leads'].queueid;
            integer totalLeadsReceived = 0;

            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {            
                    JSONToken token = parser.getCurrentToken();
                String value = parser.getText();
                system.debug('*** value ' + value);
                if(token == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                    system.debug('*** creating new lead ');           
                    l = new Lead();             
                }   
                if(value == 'totalItemCount') {
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();           
                    totalLeadsReceived = parser.getIntegerValue();     
                }
                if(value == 'enquiryId') {          
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();           
                    l.Supplier_ID__c = parser.getText();                    
                }   
                if(value == 'courseId') {           
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();           
                    l.Supplier_Course_ID__c = parser.getText();                 
                }
                if(value == 'firstName') {          
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();
                    system.debug('*** fn value ' + parser.getText());
                    l.FirstName = parser.getText();
                    l.LeadSource = 'Third Party';   
                    l.Supplier__c = 'Reed';
                    l.OwnerId = leadsQueue; 
                    l.Active_Lead__c = 'TRUE';                                                
                }   
                if(value == 'lastName') {
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();           
                    l.LastName = parser.getText();                              
                }   
                if(value == 'email') {          
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();           
                    l.Email = parser.getText();                 
                }    
                if(value == 'phone') {          
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();           
                    l.Phone = parser.getText();                 
                }        
                if(value == 'screeningQuestions') {
                    String questions = '';
                    while(parser.getText() != ']') {
                        parser.nextToken(); 
                        parser.getCurrentToken(); 
                        questions += parser.getText();
                    }
                    if(questions!='')
                        l.Notes__c = questions;
                }    
                if(value == 'course') {
                    while(parser.getText() != '}') {
                        parser.nextToken(); 
                        parser.getCurrentToken(); 
                        if(parser.getText() == 'awardingBody') {
                            parser.nextToken(); 
                            parser.getCurrentToken(); 
                            l.DistributionValue__c = 'REED ' + parser.getText(); 
                        }
                    }  
                }  
                if(value == 'site') {           
                    parser.nextToken();     
                    parser.getCurrentToken();           
                    String site = parser.getText();   
                    if(site=='Business') {
                        l.RecordTypeId = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Lead').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Corporate').getRecordTypeId();         
                        // we want the company to be blank so the adviser has to capture it
                        l.company = 'Reed Default';    
                    }
                    else {
                        l.RecordTypeId = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Lead').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Consumer').getRecordTypeId();
                        l.company = l.FirstName + ' ' + l.LastName;
                    }
                }  
                if(token == JSONToken.END_OBJECT && l != null && l.LastName != null) {   
                    system.debug('*** lead so far ' + l);                   
                    parsedLeads.add(l);
                    l = null;
                }
            }

            system.debug('** parsed leads ' + parsedLeads);

            // check if we have been unable to parse all of the leads. 
            // Email exception if total number parsed not equal to total number received.           
            if(parsedLeads.size() != totalLeadsReceived) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                string[] to = new String[] {'it.support@icslearn.co.uk'};
                email.setToAddresses( to  );
                email.setSubject( 'ERROR: Reed API Lead Parsing Issues');
                email.setPlainTextBody('The Reed API has sent across ' + totalLeadsReceived +
                                        ' Leads, however only ' + parsedLeads.size() + 
                                        ' have been successfully parsed. \n' + 
                                        ' Please find the API response below and create Leads manually if required. \n\n' +
                                        res.getBody());                    
                // Send it
                Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r =
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
                System.debug(r.size());
                System.debug(r[0].success);       
                System.debug(r[0].getErrors());
            }

            // if we get some leads, check if they have been seen already today.        
            if(parsedLeads.size() > 0) {

                List<Lead> leadsToInsert = new List<Lead>();
                List<Lead> leadsReceivedAlready = [ SELECT id, Supplier_ID__c, createdDate FROM Lead WHERE Supplier__c = 'Reed' AND createdDate = TODAY ];
                Set<String> leadIDSReceivedAlready = new Set<String>();
                for(Lead receivedLead : leadsReceivedAlready) 
                    if(!leadIDSReceivedAlready.contains(receivedLead.Supplier_ID__c))
                        leadIDSReceivedAlready.add(receivedLead.Supplier_ID__c);

                system.debug('*** lead ids received already ' + leadIDSReceivedAlready);

                for(Lead parsedLead : parsedLeads) 
                    if(!leadIDSReceivedAlready.contains(parsedLead.Supplier_ID__c))
                        leadsToInsert.add(parsedLead);                      

                // if not seen, insert them
                if(leadsToInsert.size()>0)   
                    insert leadsToInsert;       
            }               
    }

    public static HttpResponse issueReedCallout() {

        // create a call out to the Reed API. Get tthe endpoint and apikey from the custom setting.        
        Http h = new Http(); 
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        ReedAPIConfig__c config = ReedAPIConfig__c.getValues('current');
        if(config != null) {            
            req.setEndpoint(config.Endpoint__c);
            req.setMethod('GET');        
            String apikey = config.Apikey__c;
            String password = '';
            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(apikey + ':' + password);
            String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
            EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
            req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
            req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

            system.debug('req' + req);
            res = h.send(req);            
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

The classes produced by APEX2JSON

```
public class ReedAPIHandler {

    public class ReedAPIResponse {
        public Integer totalItemCount;
        public Integer totalPages;
        public List<Leads> leads;
        public List<Links> links;
    }

    public class ScreeningQuestions {
        public String question;
        public String answer;
        public String expectedAnswer;
    }

    public class Course_Z {
        public Integer courseId;
        public String title;
        public Object providerCourseRef;
        public String qualification;
        public String awardingBody;
    }

    public class Leads {
        public Integer enquiryId;
        public Integer courseId;
        public String providerCourseRef;
        public String createdOn;
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public String email;
        public String phone;
        public Object country;
        public Object postcode;
        public Object comment;
        public String courseTitle;
        public Object employmentStatus;
        public Object contactTime;
        public Object startAvailibility;
        public List<ScreeningQuestions> screeningQuestions;
        public Course course;
        public String site;
        public Object companyName;
        public Object companyJobTitle;
        public Object companySize;
    }

    public class Links {
        public String href;
        public String rel;
        public String method;
    }

    public class Course {
        public Integer courseId;
        public String title;
        public String providerCourseRef;
        public String qualification;
        public String awardingBody;
    }

    public class ScreeningQuestions_Z {
    }


    public static ReedAPIResponse parse(String json) {
        return (ReedAPIResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(json, ReedAPIResponse.class);
    }

}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to just use JSON.serialize and JSON.deserialize directly with the Apex classes, like this:

```
ReedAPIHandler.ReedAPIResponse resp = (ReedAPIHandler.ReedAPIResponse) JSON.deserialize(inboundJsonBody, ReedAPIHandler.ReedAPIResponse.class);
for (ReedAPIHandler.Leads reedLead : resp.leads) {
    Lead theLead = new Lead();
    theLead.FirstName = reedLead.lastName;
    etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this David. I get an error with this:
Variable does not exist: inboundJsonBody - should I be changing this? I have tried to add 'res' as the actual JSON response however I get this error: 
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserialize(System.HttpResponse, System.Type) from the type System.JSON

Comment: inboundJsonBody was merely an example variable, you need to replace it with whatever your HTTP response body is.

Comment: Thanks David. I have this working now. I am just looking at my test class now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ to generate the Class, it has created a test class for you. You can check the bottom of the Test class to see how to use it. The last two lines should look like this.

```
List<JSON2Apex> obj = JSON2Apex.parse(json);
System.assert(obj != null);
```

Comment: Thanks Saroj, I have the test class however I am still not sure how I replace the JSON in my current class with the JSON2APEX class. I have tried to add a for loop at JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody()); line in my code to replace it however this did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Try using like this :--`

```
public List<ReedAPIHandler > listofvalue {get;set;}


if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
                      String jsonString = res.getBody();
                      System.debug( 'jsonString:::-->>>' + jsonString);
                      if(!String.isEmpty(jsonString)){
                          listofvalue = (List<ReedAPIHandler>)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<ReedAPIHandler>.class);

                      }


     }`
```

Comment: this won't work as the response is most likely not a list given the generated class